# please give answer for this if loop only x-y is working

Tags: java, if-statement

In the below JAVA code Mul and Add operators are not working only X-y operator result i am getting please advice how to find the answer for this problem.

```
public class oppswithvalue {

void calculate(int x,int y,String op)
{
    //System.out.println(op);


    if(op=="*")
        System.out.println("X x Y : "+(x*y));
    else if(op=="+")
        System.out.println("X + Y : "+(x*y));
    else
        System.out.println("X - Y : "+(x-y));
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{

    BufferedReader ar=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Enter first number : ");
    int no1=Integer.parseInt(ar.readLine());
    System.out.println("Enter Second number : ");
    int no2=Integer.parseInt(ar.readLine());
    System.out.println("Enter an operator : ");
    String op=ar.readLine();

    oppswithvalue tt= new oppswithvalue();
    tt.calculate(no1, no2,op);
}

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 6):

In Java, you don't compare strings with `==`, you use `equals` ([more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)):

```
if(op.equals("*"))
```

If you're using Java 7 or higher, you can use strings in `switch` statements, which would make sense for a list of operators like that:

```
switch (op) {
    case "*":
        System.out.println("X x Y : "+(x*y));
        break;
    case "+":
        System.out.println("X + Y : "+(x+y)); // <== Also see note below
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("X - Y : "+(x-y));
        break;
}
```

This wouldn't compile in Java 6 and earlier.

Separately, [as Bobby points out in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26929259/please-give-answer-for-this-if-loop-only-x-y-is-working/26929312?noredirect=1#comment42404156_26929312), you have `*` where you want `+` in the `+` operation in your `if/else if`. (It's corrected in the `switch` above.)

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out. You should use `.equals()` instead of `==` when comparing objects. (String is an object in Java).

Use `==` for comparison only for primitive data types such as: `int`, `char`, `double` ..etc

Since your operator is a single character, your code can still work if you change the type of the operator from `String` to `char`

```
void calculate(int x,int y, char op)
{
    //Your codes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In java,`==` can not be used for comparing Strings. Use `.equals()` method instead.

```
if(op.equals("*"))
    System.out.println("X x Y : "+(x*y));
else if(op.equals("+"))
    System.out.println("X + Y : "+(x*y));
else
   System.out.println("X - Y : "+(x-y));
```